# how to push data into mongodb using sparkfun phant?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node.js-stream

I am new to phant and i cannot find a suitable documentation on phant using mongodb. because i have lots of data and it memory overflow occurs. and finally i fell into following error:

```
    HTTP output: { [Error: EMFILE, open 'phant_streams/4d16/83403f7611e5810d57f88174fbef/stream.csv']
  errno: -24,
  code: 'EMFILE',
  path: 'phant_streams/4d16/83403f7611e5810d57f88174fbef/stream.csv' }
events.js:87
      throw Error('Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.');
            ^
Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.
    at Error (native)
    at Function.emit (events.js:87:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/phant/node_modules/phant-manager-http/index.js:237:12)
    at PhantMeta.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/phant/node_modules/phant-meta-nedb/lib/phant-meta-nedb.js:243:14)
    at callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/phant/node_modules/phant-meta-nedb/node_modules/nedb/lib/executor.js:30:17)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/phant/node_modules/phant-meta-nedb/node_modules/nedb/lib/datastore.js:536:25
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/phant/node_modules/phant-meta-nedb/node_modules/nedb/lib/persistence.js:201:12
    at fs.js:1077:21
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

except this sometimes following error also occurs:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

thats why i want to use mongodb to prevent this error. i searched about this and finally found sparckfun library for mongodb:
https://github.com/sparkfun/phant-stream-mongodb

i installed this but nothing happened as data still not string into mongo.
so, How will i store phant data into mongodb ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, specifically trying to deploy my own Phant instance on Heroku (since I wanted to circumvent Sparkfun's 50Mb limit). After some dabbling with versions of the mongodb and mongoose libraries, I successfully forked and modified their repository so that you can either run it locally or directly deploy on heroku (just make sure you provision a MongoLab add-on). Check out my fork here: https://github.com/davidlago/phant

Hope this helps!